# How to set "performance_schema on" in mysql?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sqlyog

I want to turn `performance_schema` ON in mysql to collect statistics.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following guide is linux-specific, but should easily be adaptable to windows.

You have to check wether the mysql server binary was compiled with support for it:

```
mysqld --verbose --help|grep performance-schema
```

If the last command returned anything, you are good to go.

Enable it on server startup by putting into `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
performance_schema
```

Afterwards do a `systemctl restart mysqld` (redhat) (or `systemctl restart mysql` on debian/ubuntu) to restart the mysql server.

On how to use the performance schema engine and its output, see the manual:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema-quick-start.html

Comment: Turning this off helped me cut my memory usage from 240MB to 44MB. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation article](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema-startup-configuration.html) about it.

"To change the value of Performance Schema system variables, set them at server startup. For example, put the following lines in a my.cnf file to change the sizes of the history tables:"

`[mysqld]
performance_schema
performance_schema_events_waits_history_size=20
performance_schema_events_waits_history_long_size=15000`

Remember you have to restart you mysql server after editing the config file.