# How to turn on mysql Performance Schema on in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I am trying to turn on mysql Performance Schema in phpmyadmin. I read some article like:
[how to know mysql my.cnf location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-to-know-mysql-my-cnf-location)
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-quick-start.html
[How to on Performance_schema in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273426/how-to-on-performance-schema-in-mysql)

The problem is that in my hosting cpanel i dont know how to access their terminal. And i tried to query insert manually into a performance schema variable and i get this:

[image]

After browsing around phpmyadmin i found an option to edit changes to that variable but i see this:

[image]

I do believe my user in mysql database have the highest possible access right but i am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your privileges with this statement:

```
SHOW GRANTS
```

You do need privileges to access `performance_schema.*`

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-table-characteristics.html says:

> Privileges are as for other databases and tables:
>
> - To retrieve from performance_schema tables, you must have the SELECT privilege.
> - To change those columns that can be modified, you must have the UPDATE privilege.
> - To truncate tables that can be truncated, you must have the DROP privilege.

It would be normal in a hosted environment that your privileges are restricted only to the databases created for your hosting account.

You'd have to ask your hosting company technical support if you can additionally have at least SELECT privilege on `performance_schema`.

---

Re your comment:

USAGE privilege just means you can connect, you cannot query any tables or do anything else.

`ALL PRIVILEGES ON user\_dev.*` means you have privileges **only on your user_dev database**, but no privileges on any other database (like performance_schema).

You'll have to talk to your hosting company about their policy about privileges on performance_schema.

Comment: I still dont have access even though it seem like is saying GRANT ALL ACCESS. [GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'user'@'110.169.999.999' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret>]
[GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `user\_dev`.* TO 'user'@'110.169.999.999'] @Bill karwin